# Arch Linux pacman error: failed retrieving file

Tags: arch-linux, software-installation, pacman, elinks

I just installed Arch Linux today. I am trying to install elinks using

```
pacman -S elinks
```

And I get a long, long list of:

```
error: failed retrieving file 'elinks-0.13-17-i686.pkg.tar.xz' from some.mirror : Could not resolve host: some.mirror
```

The same happens if I try to install any other software. The only thing I could think of based on what I read is a connection problem, but I'm on the same connection that I used to install the OS, and that was just a few minutes ago.

Comment: The live medium will connect automatically; once you have installed Arch, you have to set up networking yourself...

Comment: @jasonwryan Thanks! Like I said, I'm new to this...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found an answer, thanks to jasonwryan's comment.

I tried lots of things to get my ethernet connection to work and it still didn't work till I researched the `netctl` command (https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/netctl, `man netctl`).

`ls /etc/netctl` revealed that there were no profiles in my /etc/netctl folder, so I ran

```
cp /etc/netctl/examples/ethernet-dhcp /etc/netctl
netctl start ethernet-dhcp
```

Before that, I had run (from https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=151483)

```
systemctl enable dhcpcd@eth0.service
systemctl start dhcpcd@eth0.service
```

And voila, the internet was working. Not sure which of the commands was responsible, but now it works.

Answer (score 45):

Although this has been answered, I encountered the same issue. I resolved it by updating my databases while installing. For instance:

```
sudo pacman -Syu elinks
```

Comment: Adding the `yu` after the `S` seemed to make the difference. I'd already tried `--disable-download-timeout` which didn't work on it's own so I had `-Syu` *and* `--disable-download-timeout` and it then worked.

Answer (score 8):

Update your pacman mirrors:

```
sudo pacman-mirrors -g
```

Comment: This helped me, I think my mirrors got borked. Didn't realize this command existed! (Using manjaro over here)

Comment: Glad to help :)

Comment: Had to create a new account just so I can upvote :) Thank you, fixed it for me with a single command.

Comment: `sudo: pacman-mirrors: command not found` but adding the disable timout and `Syu` solved: `sudo pacman -Syu --asdeps --disable-download-timeout graphicsmagick`

Answer (score 0):

You can also download the package(*pkg.tar.zst file*) manually and use the command

```
sudo pacman -U package_name.pkg.tar.zst
```

I used this method as `sudo pacman -Syu` command wanted to install few extra packages of total size ~200mb, and all i have was a 8kb/s net connection

Comment: 8kb/s in 2020 in kerala? Unbelievable