# arch linux: understanding error msg in retrieving file

Tags: arch-linux, pacman

I have installed the arch linux. I am using wifi-menu to connect to wireless network. But every time a package is installed using 'pacman -Syu file' it give errors and in next line the repository is installed.
I have gone through similar answer on posted like one ->[here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/326291/arch-linux-pacman-error-failed-retrieving-file)

```
error retrieving file.pkg.tar.xz from arch.nimukaito.net: could not resolve file    
file                                          [#############]100%
```

Here i have concern why is the error coming and if error is shown then how is the file installation getting completed.
Can anyone help me understand what is going here as i am trying to learn the basics ?

Comment: Are you able to `ping 8.8.8.8`?

Comment: Yes, As i stated in the question i am able to access internet and install packages. I am not able to understand why am i getting the error in the every alternate line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are able to access and download the file because the mirror is online, it gives you an error because the mirror has DNS issues. If you try and lookup arch.nimukaito.net in your browser you will get a `DNS address could not be found` error, but you still can access and download from it, using the saved copy.

I suggest you change your mirror arch.nimukaito.net in `/etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist` to a different one and then `pacman -Syyu` then try and install a package.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can't vote up as i hove only 1 reputation on unix stackexchange.    
Just as i understood after looking the mirrorlist file.
There were different mirrors listed there. It searches on the mirror listed there from the start. The first mirror has DNS issues from my browser also. I comment that mirror and now it downloads without errors.

Comment: Could you explain the behaviour of `pacman -Syyu`? That would be a great expansion to this answer.